# Php array modulo every second value

Tags: php, arrays, modulo

I have a question. I have this array of the alphabet.
And every even letter needs to be !$letter, so it needs to echo out !b, !d, !f

I'm unsure how to do this. I've been told to use the modulo, % for this.

But reading a lot about it on the internet and things haven't gotten any clearer for me.

I appreciate anyone that can help me on this matter!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by `!b`? You literally want to write `"!b"`?

Comment: Do you understand what modulo does? In case you don't, it just returns the remainder of dividing two numbers. So, if you divide 5 by 2, you'd get 4 with a remainder of 1. You should know from your basic mathematics courses that can be cleanly divided by 2 is an even number. If something can cleanly be divided by another number, then the remainder is 0. Thus, if you check if the remainder of `$i / 2 == 0`, then you know if the number is even or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($alphabet as $i => $letter) {
    echo (($i % 2) == 1 ? '!' : '') . $letter;
}
```

`$i` is the position of the letter in the array; since array indexes start from 0, even letters will have odd indexes.

`$i % 2` is `0` when `$i` is even, `1` when it's odd. This is grade school arithmetic, which should be a prerequisite for a programming career.

Comment: Thanks looks exactly as i want to, only this puts the ! before every odd number letter. What should i change to make it place an ! before every second?

Comment: You can either change the 1 to a 0, or you can swap the positions of the `'!'` and the `''`

Comment: @Farewyth Read my additional explanation. I think it should do what you want as written, unless you've created your array strangely.

Comment: You could also check if the first bit is 0 or 1: `$i & 1 === 0`. This is often more performant method of checking for even/odd in most languages, but I don't think it gives an edge in `PHP` if memory serves.