# Jquery nth-child selector in an array

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I want to use the nth-child selector to return the even values of the array.  This is what I have:

**Javascript Code**

```
var blog = Note01,Date01, Username01,Note02,Date02, Username02,
for(var i=0; i<blog.length-1; i++){
    alert(blog + " :nth-child(even)").html();
}
```

**This is the array**

```
[0]Note01
[1]Date01
[2]Username01
[3]Note02
[4]Date02
[5]Username02
```

**This is what I think should return:**

```
Username01, Date02
```

How can I accomplish this using the nth-child selector?

Comment: Could you please format your post properly? Code as code and text as text. It would make it easier to read! http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. FWIW, `var blog = Note01,Date01, Username01,Note02,Date02, Username02,` is not valid JS. And `:nth-child` is a **CSS selector** to select DOM elements. It has **nothing** to do with arrays *at all*.

Comment: What you're looking for is the [`modulo`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator.

Comment: You can use nth-child that way, just with proper code. See this page and the demo at the bottom of it. http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: duplicate -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243355/how-do-i-output-even-elements-of-array-the-right-way

Comment: another -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483416/php-array-modulo-every-second-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use nth-child for this. You could make use of the modulo operator:

Given:

```
var A = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];
```

Use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over the array:

```
$.each(A, function(k, v) {
    if (k % 2 == 0) console.log(v);
});
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q4tHG/)***

Or you can do it with a simple `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) console.log(A[i]);
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote `0 % 2 === 0` is true, so it would return the first value in the array as well.

Comment: You can use nth-child for that. See the demo at the bottom of this page: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: I got it to work using the modulo operator.  Thanks.